# Recursive calls into a user’s hand

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm studying recursive function in python and i don't understand why this is wrong. Can you help me?

The exercise is:

> In the code below, I have implemented a recursive implementation of asking the user for a string, in which only lower case letters may be used.  When someone enters a  string with  an  illegal  character in  it,  a  recursive  call to  the  function itself  will  ask  fora new string.  This looks like it avoids using the loop-and-a-half to ask the user for new inputs on incorrect inputs. While it is always a bad idea to place control over the depth of recursive calls into a user’s hands, this implementation actually is not only bad, it is also quite wrong.  Can you see what is wrong with it, and how that is caused?  (Note:  it is not the letter < 'a' or letter > 'z' expression, those comparisons are just fine.)

```
def get_input( prompt ):
    value = input( prompt )
    for letter in value:
        if letter < 'a' or letter > 'z':
           print( "The character", letter, "is not allowed!")
           value = get_input( prompt ) # DO NOT DO THIS!
    return value

s = get_input( "Give a string of lower case letters: " )
print( "The user entered:", s )
```

> Let me stress once more that the idea above is a bad one.  You should not use recursion for commonplace problems that can just as well be solved by iterations.  Recursion is for exceptional circumstances. Do not see this as an example of recursion, see it as an example of how not to use recursion!   The main reason I put it here is that I sometimes observe students writing such code, and I want to make explicit that that is not a good idea!

Comment: your indentation is wrong after def

Comment: Edited but the author of the book refers to an error in the logic of the code. I can't find the problem.

Comment: it's calling recursively for every wrong character that occurs, not just after if any character is invalid.  so if I type 123456789 it would call get_input 9 times.  I guess a simple "fix" is to just put a return before get_input instead of value =

Comment: Thank you. That's the only problem with this code? I mean nothing conceptually wrong?

Comment: That is in itself actually conceptually wrong, because you want it to reject after the first invalid character found (or just check and set a boolean flag true or false or something similar) (for example you could implement it to complain about all invalid characters found, and only call recursively after it finishes checking all characters ie: after the for loop).  If you call for all of them, it will iterate over it 9 times and overwrite the inputs, so it will continue past when you input something valid and overwrite its value with later inputs that may or may not be valid discarding valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing "123456789" would cause get_input to get called 9 times, due to the for loop having to iterate over and reject all 9 characters, and call itself recursively 9 times before returning value.
A simple fix is to put a return instead of `value =` to have it terminate the function immediately and return the next valid input retrieved from the recursive call.

```
def get_input( prompt ):
    value = input( prompt )
    for letter in value:
        if letter < 'a' or letter > 'z':
           print( "The character", letter, "is not allowed!")
           return get_input( prompt ) # re-prompt for input and return (and exit function)
    return value

s = get_input( "Give a string of lower case letters: " )
print( "The user entered:", s )
```